# Issue with using oswalk

Tags: python, file, for-loop, directory, operating-system

I'm new in python and I'm trying to find every file which ends with .txt in directory and it's subdirectory using os.walk. I tried to do this, but after the line for file in files the function ends. My code:

```
import os
def find_all_txt(directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.txt'):
                print(file)
print(find_all_txt('exerr'))
```

Terminal after inputing ls:

```
root@DESKTOP-TIPFBEG:~/exercise/exerr# ls
exr.py  fileee.txt
```

Comment: add `print(os.listdir(directory))` as first line of the method, to ensure it reads the good directory

Comment: Can you tell me in which line should I do it? Because function ends in 3rd line (for root etc)

Comment: do it as first line of the method, add `print(os.listdir(directory), os.path.abspath(directory))`

Comment: The output is not such file or directory :/

Comment: If you are executing the code in folder `exerr` it can't find `exerr` that is normal. Run it one level higher and it'll find it or call `find_all_txt('.')`

Comment: Thank you, can you explain it to me why I can't find it using on exercise. The second question is that why it didn't show me every file.txt in every directory, but it showed me only file which were in exercise?

Comment: "The second question is that why it didn't show me every file.txt in every directory, but it showed me only file which were in exercise?" Because *that's the folder where you told it to look*. Just like how when you used the `ls` command at the terminal in that folder, it didn't show you every file on your hard drive. The reason your code is done after the first `for file in files:` loop is that there aren't any directories for `os.walk` to recurse into.

Comment: Oh, I think I misread a bit. The code doesn't show you any output for `find_all_txt('exerr')` because *you are already in that folder*, so you are trying to look for *another* folder with the same name within the current one. "Thank you, can you explain it to me why I can't find it using on exercise." I can't understand what you mean.